# Clojure code parsing

Tags: parsing, clojure

I'm writing a DSL and I want to implement debugging.

However, I lose all the line info because i read user input with (read-string the-input) and then it is no longer source, but s expressions which are evaluated with eval.

First thing I thought about is this, simply add code (without user's knowledge) at the end of each line, like so:

```
(user-func-a)
(user-func-b)
```

Would become:

```
(user-func-a) (my-source-index 0)
(user-func-b) (my-source-index 1)
```

However, this would fall apart in multi line form:

```
(+ (my-source-index 0)
 1 (my-source-index 1)
 2 (my-source-index 2)
 3) (my-source-index 3)
```

Then I wanted to implement bracket tracking, so, that only when parens are closed I'd add source index:

```
(+
 1
 2
 3) (my-source-index 3)
```

But then I thought, wait, what about comments? I have to track for ';' too or it'll be this:

```
(+
 1 ;) (my-source-index 1)
 2 (my-source-index 2)
 3) (my-source-index 3)
```

Even if I implemented that i'd have to track where the comment symbol was not in quotes (part of the text) and so on.

I didn't go much further after that (there probably would be even more quirks...) and came to here. Is there any library for clojure to parse code, find out the context surrounding the line and to avoid such hassles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IndexingPushBackReader` from `clojure.tools.reader` should do the job. According to documentation it adds line/column metadata to symbols, vectors and maps (but not literals).

See the following:

```
(require '[clojure.tools.reader :as r])
(require '[clojure.tools.reader.reader-types :as rt])

(def reader (rt/indexing-push-back-reader
             "(+ \n;; comment here \n 1 \n a)"))

(def s-expr (r/read reader)) ;; => (+ 1 a)

(meta s-expr) ;; => {:line 1, :column 1, :end-line 4, :end-column 4}

(nth s-expr 0) ;; => +
(meta (nth s-expr 0)) ;; => {:line 1, :column 2, :end-line 1, :end-column 3}

(nth s-expr 1) ;; => 1
(meta (nth s-expr 1)) ;; => nil (no metadata on literals)

(nth s-expr 2) ;; => a
(meta (nth s-expr 2)) ;; => {:line 4, :column 2, :end-line 4, :end-column 3}
```